# getAction missing in editor instance of editorDidMount method - monaco editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

**Problem**
I am trying to use react-monaco-editor to render a json code. When I try to format the json , I was suggested the method: `editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run()` . The code that I use is

```
const editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(editor);
      editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run()
    }, 300);
  };
```

but I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null`
Could some one please help me understand why I am missing getAction method in the editor instance.

One other thing that I noticed is that, when checking in the context-menu(right-click).. I dont see the `Format Document`. Aslo the action `editor.action.formatDocument` is missing in the `_actions` object of the editor instance. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be an issue created by myself. I had to add the option `format` in the list of `features` of the `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`(https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin). But one downside is I still cannot find the `editor.getAction()` method. Instead I had to use the `editor.trigger()` method to simulate a format action throught code.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.